# A Django Issue when testing my website with a dropdown

Tags: django

I am following the tutorial at [Django Tutorials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdVHA.png).  The goal is to get a dropdown list to display a logout when I click on it.  [![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here is my settings.py where the static files are held:

```
    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
    
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    ]
    
    LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
    
I am getting a HTTP 404 error because of this.  It's saying GET HTTP/1.1 404 1683 when I run it.


  [1]: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/25/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-4.html#displaying-menu-for-authenticated-users
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/op2g1.png
```

Because of the error, when I click on the arrow, it won't show me the dropdown list.  Can anyone show me how to fix this and what this error means?

The intent of this code below is to display a dropdown list of the User that was authenticated and when I click on it, it allows me to logout.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Django Boards</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainMenu" aria-controls="mainMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{ user.username }}
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="userMenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">My account</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Change password</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The directory listing is here.
[image]

Comment: i see your post second time can you please share your html code in the post whole html with base file if there is any

Comment: Sure.  I'll post it when I edit it, and then you can see the bigger picture.

Comment: I added the HTML File that was used.

Comment: I am following the tutorial link on https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/25/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-4.html#logout and I seem to be doing something wrong.

Comment: i don't think you have any problem in css or something or in your code i think you put something in the wrong file at the end of the tutorial this link is given cross check what went wrong this still doesn't work let me know 
https://github.com/sibtc/django-beginners-guide/tree/v0.4-lw

Comment: Please also show your project directory tree, in particular the `static` folder where you have a file called `bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: Here's the tree that you requested.

Comment: Right now when I tested the site, I got this error below.
GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1 404 1683

Can anyone tell me what this error means and how to fix it?